# $\operatorname{rank}(g\circ f)\le \min\{\operatorname{rank}(f), \operatorname{rank}(g)\}$ proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have these two linear transformations $f:V \to W$ and $g: W \to Z$, where $V, W, Z$ are vector spaces and $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $Z$. Now I need to prove that $$\operatorname{rank}(g \circ f) \le \min\{\operatorname{rank}(f), \text{rank}(g)\}$$

I kind of see it intuitively, but have no idea how to prove it.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Ihf yes, it was a typo

Comment: If you write \text{rank} rather than \operatorname{rank} then you don't automatically get proper spacing in things like $a\operatorname{rank}b$ or $a\operatorname{rank}(b).$ I include both examples to show the context-dependent nature of the spacing: less space appears to the right of $\operatorname{rank}$ in the second example. You'll just see $a\text{rank}b$ instead.

Comment: @MichaelHardy but how does it help to solve the problem asked in this question?

Comment: @ivana14 : See my answer below.

Comment: @ArnaudD. That question has a title that makes it look like a duplicate, but it seems to actually be asking "how can the inequality be strict?" Or at least, that's how it's been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The point would be that you cannot get a larger set of linearly independent vectors out of a linear transformation than you put into it. Thus, suppose $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)$ are linearly independent. Then there are no scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ that are not all $0$ such that $c_1 f(x_1) + \cdots+c_nf(x_n) = 0.$ But if $c_1 x_1 + \cdots c_n x_n=0,$ then $c_1 f(x_1) + \cdots+c_nf(x_n) = 0.$ Therefore there can be no scalars $c_1,\ldots, c_n$ that are not all $0$ such that $c_1x_1+\cdots+c_n x_n=0.$ In other words if $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)$ are linearly independent, then so are $x_1,\ldots,x_n.$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $U$ is a subspace of $W$, then $\dim g(U) \le \dim U$ and $\dim g(U) \le \dim g(W)$.